# How to override an existing package version in GitHub Packages

Tags: github, github-actions

In my Gradle project I have a hardcoded project version - SNAPSHOT.

When I push a new version - everything is OK, but if I push the same version for 2nd time - publishing fails. How can I tell GitHub that I want to override existing package?

For GitHub Actions I have a workflow to publish that project on every push to the main branch:

```
name: Publish package to GitHub Packages
on:
  push:
    branches: ['main']
jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'corretto'
          java-version: '18'
          cache: 'gradle'

      - name: Publish package
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
        with:
          arguments: publish
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

I'm expecting a new package with the same version to be publish to the GitHub Packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I did not found any GitHub Action for my task, I decided to create one: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/version-cleaner-action

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but first you need to [delete that package version](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/deleting-and-restoring-a-package) and then republish it.

But keep in mind that:

> On GitHub if you have the required access, you can delete:
>
> - an entire private package
> - an entire public package, if there's not more than 5000 downloads of any version of the package
> - a specific version of a private package
> - a specific version of a public package, if the package version doesn't have more than 5,000 downloads

Comment: Ok, thx for for info, I've decided to create an Action for that: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/version-cleaner-action